# bootstrap modal button is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a little problem on my website. the button is not responding when clicked

the button is at the footer of the bootstrap modal dialog

this is the html code of my button

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btnrelogin btn btn-primary">
                Login
         </button>
        </div>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btnrelogin').click(function () {
                document.getElementById('retypecheckpassword').value = "Hello";
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is "retypecheckpassword"?

Comment: its an input for text

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's something covering the button. Try right clicking and inspecting the element to see if you're not actually clicking the button.

Perhaps the jQuery or bootstrap.js is not loading correctly or another script error is occurring. Check your browser's console for errors.

Additionally, only html input tags have the value property so if you're trying to set the contents of an element other an element such as

```
<input type="text"...
```

you should use

```
.text('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a label try setting the .text("hello");